# Passing sensitive information to cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Is there an "official" solution for passing sensitive information, such as API keys, to Google Cloud Functions? In particular it would be nice to avoid passing this information as arguments to the function since it will be the same for every invocation. AWS Lambda has a [built-in solution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-env_console.html) using encrypted environment variables for this. Is there some similar approach for Google Cloud Functions?

I could imagine using a cloud storage bucket or cloud datastore for this, but that feels very manual.

Comment: I wrote an answer then realized you don't seem to use Firebase. I left the answer up, just in case it's useful.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using Cloud Functions with Firebase, you're looking for [environment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

With that, you deploy configuration data from the Firebase CLI:

```
firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

And then read it in your functions with:

```
functions.config().someservice.id
```

Comment: Do the environment variables get stored in the same place as the database - eg if someone gets access to firebase db - can they get the encrypted key?

Comment: These configuration values are not stored in the database, but in a separate configuration service.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you know by any chance what is the best analogue (approach) of config-env for Google Cloud Functions? Not Firebase functions, but Google Cloud Functions https://cloud.google.com/functions

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I would not suggest using environment variables for storing this kind of data. Those are accessible throughout the whole lifecycle of the function's execution, and any 3rd party package can access them directly. It's highly possible to have the environment configuration accidentally logged somewhere as well. Looking at Firebase's docs, there it's said NOT to use environment config for such scenarios.

Comment: @BilgerYahov In that case where would you suggest such data be stored as i'm currently trying to use Firebase Cloud functions to hide my 3rd Party API keys

Comment: With v2 (currently in public preview), `functions.config()` gets removed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Google Secret Manager.
https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs

See this article for an example: 
https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-secrets-in-google-cloud-functions-5aem

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are outdated, since firebase-functions v3.18.0 the recommended way is to use secrets (like env but passed explicitly to specific functions and without .env but a remote config) : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?hl=en#secret-manager

> Before environment variable support was released in firebase-functions v3.18.0, using functions.config() was the recommended approach for environment configuration. This approach is still supported, but we recommend all new projects use environment variables instead, as they are simpler to use and improve the portability of your code.

You can use it like this:
`firebase functions:secrets:set MY_SECRET`

And answer a value to the CLI.

And then in your function:

```
exports.processPayment = functions
  // Make the secret available to this function
  .runWith({ secrets: ["MY_SECRET"] })
  .onCall((data, context) => {
    // Now you have access to process.env.MY_SECRET
  });
```

Comment: hi, and how to deal with different envs?

Comment: @AndryxaPiddubnjak the general recommandation if I remember is to have different Firebase projects with a CI that deploy to the right project based on git branch

Comment: this is not a free option as it is built-in in AWS lambda...

Answer (score 1):

Few options that you can go about this:

1. GCP Runtime Configuration. Set up a schema that can be only accessed by your service account and put your secret there. You do that prior to your deployment. Your app should be able to use Runtime Configuration API to access these. You can use this nifty library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/rcloadenv
2. Generate a JS on the fly including that information as part of your cloud function build/deploy and include that file as part of you cloud function.
3. Use Google KMS to store the keys and access it with KMS's API

Answer (score 0):

As for now, there's no way to do this.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907643

Comment: Have you been able to find a suitable workaround? I'm thinking of keeping a config file encrypted and passing the key through PubSub as part of the message...

Comment: It is not advised to use Environment variables for sensitive data - Google's documentation: "Environment variables can be used for function configuration, but are not recommended as a way to store secrets such as database credentials or API keys. These more sensitive values should be stored outside both your source code and outside environment variables. ... may result in the contents of environment variables being sent to logs," etc. cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var

Comment: @MatthewP `stored outside both your source code and outside environment variables` where is that magical place ?

Comment: @Michael On Google we've found one approach is to use Google Cloud Storage (auto encrypted by default) and then to use KMS to encrypt the file that is put into Google Cloud Storage (this allows very granular access control, rotation of keys, encrypted twice, etc.). The keys are then accessed using service accounts at runtime. Sounds like a hassle but it can be implemented within 30 minutes - it's just working out the best way to do it the first time you set it up that takes a bit longer but we think it is easily worth the extra effort.