# Firebase Functions: Where should I store api keys?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase callable function that utilizes `GoogleAuth` to access `androidpublisher`.

In order to authenticate the request, I have to supply data from my `service-account-google-play.json` file which contains **sensitive information**

The question is, where should I store this file? right now it's inside my functions folder which I deployed to Firebase, but that doesn't seem secure.

I thought about storing the necessary variables such as `private_key` inside a `.env` file, but apparently, that isn't safe either (???)

I heard about services, such as Cloud Secrets, but I don't want to pay for a service that should be free.

How should I store my API keys without Cloud Secrets?

Code Sample:

```html
 exports.verifyPurchaseAndroid = async ({payload, authUser, firestore}) => {
    try {
        const pathGoogleServiceAccount = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS; // path to json which resides inside the same directory as this function
        const jsonGoogleServiceAccount = await ReadFile(pathGoogleServiceAccount);

        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            credentials: {
                client_email: jsonGoogleServiceAccount.client_email,
                private_key: jsonGoogleServiceAccount.private_key,
            },
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'],
        });
        
        const authClient = await auth.getClient();
        const packageName = process.env.BUNDLEIDENTIFIER;
        const productId = payload?.productId;
        const token = payload?.receiptData;

        
        // console.log(authClient);
        google.options({ auth: authClient });
            // packageName,productId,token you can get from request sent from android
            const purchaseResponse = await google
                .androidpublisher({
                    version: 'v3',
                }).purchases.products.acknowledge({
                    // The package name of the application the inapp product was sold in (for example, 'com.some.thing').
                    packageName: packageName,
                    // The inapp product SKU (for example, 'com.some.thing.inapp1').
                    productId: productId,
                    // The token provided to the user's device when the inapp product was purchased.
                    token: token,
                    // Request body metadata
                    requestBody: {
                        // request body parameters
                        "developerPayload": "my_developerPayload",
                    },
                });
                
                console.log(purchaseResponse);

    } catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing sensitive information to cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959284/passing-sensitive-information-to-cloud-functions)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Yeah I saw that one, which is how I became aware of Cloud Secrets. The other methods are deprecated and don't work with gen2 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> right now it's inside my functions folder which I deployed to firebase, but that doesn't seem secure.

Unless you can say what the specific problem is, there isn't a problem. End users won't have access to the data in your functions deployment unless you manage to write code to expose it to the caller.

> thought about storing the neccesary variables such as private_key inside a .env file, but apparently that isn't safe either (???)

Same thing - unless you can say what the specific problem is, there isn't a problem.

The problem you're having right now is that you haven't defined what "safe" or "secure" actually means for your application.  Without a definition, it's impossible to tell what's suitable for your situation.  If your goal is simply to keep some data out from public view, then you're probably already doing that.  But keep in mind that others with admin level access to your project will still be able to see what you've deployed.

Comment: I apologize for not conveying the message clearly enough: My intention is to create a callable function which receives an in app purchase receipt that utilizes GoogleAuth in order to verify it. Inside that function, I'm creating a JWT in order to access my service account (that's where the 'sensitive data' comes in, which is just the json key I downloaded from google cloud). So safe/secure in this context means "Can users who make the call can somehow access said json"? Probably a dumb question to ask, but this is my first firebase project!

Comment: Without seeing all of the code, it's impossible to tell.  But as I said, unless you explicitly make it possible, then it's not possible.

Comment: I edited the code sample. Hopefully that makes it clearer!